# Use wordpress plugin only on subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, subdomain

I have installed Wordpress on the main domain. Now I have created a sub-domain in cpanel. I want to use the plugin WP Job Manager on that sub-domain only and not on the main domain.

So its like I want the private company jobs listed on that sub-domain only with this plugin.

I have no idea what to do :(

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: You don't have wordpress installed on your subdomain?

Comment: No.. Do I need to install there as well?? So in short I need two WP install and 2 database as well???

Comment: I think I am not getting your query exactly, but if you want a wp plugin to work then you have to install it. If you want to it to run on home/public_html ie on root, then install wp there, if you want to run wp plugin on home/public_html/sub_folder then again you have to install wp there. WP plugins need WP setup classes and functions to work.

Comment: Ok. Now I already installed WP on public_html which is the main domain. Now I have a subdomain, ie, public_html/subfolder. But if I install WP there as well then I will have to manage that like a different site altogether. I want to manage the subdomain as well as the main domain with one WP dashboard. I heard of Multisite but I don't understand what is it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwGC-_KH0jY , I think this will help you

Comment: Ok I got this thing working now. I did took a bit of time because I was getting some errors which are now solved. Learning a bit more so that I can setup perfectly with SEO as well. Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: Well I can't see that option :( It looks like this http://i.imgur.com/NHVUHbr.png

Comment: Very sorry for that :(

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Wordpress Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) and try to setup the multidomain setup and install that particular plugin in your subdomain only.